# Can I chunk an InputStream in kotlin by using the sequence/collections APIs?

Tags: kotlin, collections, inputstream, chunking

I'm currently looking at putting together something like the following in my project to make iterating over unknown-length `InputStream`s easier:

```kotlin
fun InputStream.chunk(size: Int, block: (ByteArray) -> Unit) {

    val buffer = ByteArray(size)

    while (this.read(buffer) > 0) {
        block(buffer)
    }
}
```

I noticed however that kotlin has chunking support in its collections which got me to thinking about whether that's something I could leverage instead of coming up with my own solution.

So this is more of a gut check to ensure I'm not reinventing the wheel: Is there any idiomatic way that I can apply a scope function to an `InputStream` in kotlin, preserving the semantics of streaming and not reading it entirely into memory?

Comment: `inputStream.buffered().iterator().asSequence().chunked(size).forEach {
        // todo
    }`?

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, `inputStream.readBytes().asIterable().chunked(size)`.

Comment: Will either of these cause the whole `InputStream` to be read into memory?

Comment: (my hunch is that the latter will)

Comment: What does that give you that [`BufferedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) doesn't?